# error occured when running maven project

Tags: maven, maven-3, appium, appium-ios

I am new to maven project and 
i am facing problem when i am running a maven project. My project use appium.

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver
at grab.main.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

my pom is

```
    <dependency>              
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
        <version>2.48.2</version>                               
     </dependency>           
     <dependency>              
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
        <version>6.8.5</version>                              
        <scope>test</scope>                                     
    </dependency>
    <dependency>              
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>                             
        <version>4.1.1</version>                              
        <scope>test</scope>                                     
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the dependency for Java-Client only for test `<scope>test</scope>`. Remove the scope and the dependency is available at runtime:

```
<dependency>              
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>                             
    <version>4.1.1</version>                              
</dependency>
```